# How can I run multiple inotifywait loops in Bash?

Tags: bash

I have a script that ran as a daemon listening to a file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo '1'
while inotifywait -e close_write /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/automations.yaml
do
    echo 'automations'
    curl -X POST -H "x-ha-access: pass" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://hassbian.local:8123/api/services/automation/reload
done;
```

I wanted to listen to several files, and tried adding two more loops:

```
while inotifywait -e close_write /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/groups.yaml
do
    echo 'gropus'
    curl -X POST -H "x-ha-access: pass" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://hassbian.local:8123/api/services/group/reload
done;

while inotifywait -e close_write /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/core.yaml
do
    echo 'core'
    curl -X POST -H "x-ha-access: pass" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://hassbian.local:8123/api/services/homeassistant/reload_core_config
done;
```

I realized that the first loop never gets closed so the other ones never get started, but not sure how I should solve this.

Comment: Why are you using  a loop in the first place? Are you expecting the file to be reopened and closed multiple times, calling `curl` each time it gets closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run the first loop in a background process so that it doesn't block your script. You may want to run *each* loop in the background for symmetry, then wait on them at the end of the script.

```
while inotifywait -e close_write /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/groups.yaml
do
    echo 'gropus'
    curl -X POST -H "x-ha-access: pass" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://hassbian.local:8123/api/services/group/reload
done &

while inotifywait -e close_write /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/core.yaml
do
    echo 'core'
    curl -X POST -H "x-ha-access: pass" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://hassbian.local:8123/api/services/homeassistant/reload_core_config
done &

wait
```

However, you can run `inotifywait` in monitor mode and monitor multiple files, piping its output into a single loop. (Caveat: like any line-oriented output format, this cannot cope with filenames containing newlines. See the `--format` and `--csv` options for dealing with filenames containing whitespace.)

```
files=(
  /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/groups.yaml
  /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/core.yaml
)

take_action () {
    echo "$1"
    curl -X POST "x-ha-access: pass" -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
      http://hassbian.local:8123/api/services/"$2"
}

inotifywait -m -e close_write "${files[@]}" |
  while IFS= read -r fname _; do
    case $fname in
      */groups.yaml) take_action "groups" "group/reload" ;;
      */core.yaml)   take_action "core" "homeassistant/reload_core_config" ;;
    sac
  done
```